# Web API returns results but doesn't hit breakpoint even when symbols are correctly loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This is the weirdest thing that has ever happened to me so please hear me out.

1. Symbols are getting loaded properly. So thats not an issue.
2. API is working and the data is valid.
3. I've 2 controllers in the same project. One controller's breakpoint is hit when I make a GET request. But the second controller's breakpoint isn't getting hit. However it does return results correctly.

I'm putting a breakpoint at the constructor level (and have tried everywhere else) but not sure what is going wrong.

The code is pretty normal C# MVC web api.

Does anyone know what might cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

One trick I like to use is to use `Exception`s. First you change some public method in your "bad" `Controller` to just unconditionally `throw` some dummy `Exception`. Then call that method from whatever uses you WebAPI and make sure the `Exception` is actually thrown. Sometimes something get cached and code is not actually re-compiled or something.

Then attach your debugger and see if it catches the `Exception`. You might be attaching to a wrong process.

Next modify code to `throw` and `catch` that `Exception` and just log it. The trick here is that VS Debugger has an option to stop even on caught aka "user-handled" exceptions: see configuration [here for VS up to 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh(v=vs.120).aspx) and [here for VS 2015+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx). Then you can see if symbols actualy matches the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue - try this site out that might help
[breakpoint issue](http://forums.asp.net/t/1428325.aspx?debug%20web%20service%20project%20in%20same%20solution%20as%20web%20site%20project%20)

Meanwhile try to force a breakpoint
      System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Comment: just tried. it still didn't hit. taking a look at your link now. thanks!

Comment: Click on the properties of your solution file > Startup Project.  Select Multiple startup projects and select both your Site and your Service as Start selected

Answer (score 0):

Does the controller, which works but doesn't hit the breakpoint, output cache whatever it is that is being generated? If it is, the data will be returned by whatever is caching it, and the controller won't be instantiated.

It's not clear whether you are using MVC or WebAPI controllers or what you are returning. However if it's MVC you could look for the `[OutputCache()]` attribute. You could also keep an eye out for other cache related headers which might be getting added.

Depending on the caching strategy you might be able to circumvent it by adding a random query string value so that it has to create a new cache key. For example:

```
http://example.com/some/path/1234?cow=moo
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

1.Go to project "Build settings"

2.Search Debug

3.Under Apple Clang - Code Generation check "Optimization Level"

4.Set Debug to None [-OO]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem just a moment ago before writing this down... Try going to properties of you webapi and compare if the project url found in the web section is the same as the url specified in your website's webconfig file. As for my problem, the website was pointing to the webapi properly which allows any code changes in the webapi to be read however, the debugger is pointed in the wrong place thus it cannot read any breakpoints you place.